# проблема открытия таблицы excel после ее создания через phpexcel

Tags: php, excel

Добрый день, с помощью `phpexcel` создаю пустую таблицу. Таблица создается и сохраняется без проблем, но при открытии вот такая вот ошибка. [image: ошибка открытия файла]
код

```
//date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
require_once $dir.'/php_scripts/php_excel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once $dir.'/php_scripts/php_excel/Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation.php';
require_once $dir.'/php_scripts/php_excel/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php';

$obj = new PHPExcel;
$obj->setActiveSheetindex(0);
$a_sheet = $obj->getActiveSheet; 

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-
officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="products.xlsx"');
$objWr = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($obj,'Excel2007');
$objWr->save('php://output');
exit();
```

вроде как `date_default_timezone_set` должно было решить проблему, но безрезультатно. Если `Excel2007` поменять на `Excel5` и `application/vnd.openxmlformats-
    officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` на `application/vnd.excel` - таже ошибка. Как можно решить данную проблему? Использую openserver

Comment: с чеге вы вдруг взяли что timezone решит проблему? зы: вы файл полученный откройте в блокноте каком нить, и проверьте, что там нет никаких нотисов и варнингов от пхп.

Comment: В нете нашел, у кого то после этого все работало. Открывал, там кроме кода страницы и строк в конце с какой то непонятной кодировкой ничего нет

Answer (score 0):

Выглядит всё правильно. Но может различаться кодировка с которой у вас работает PHP, и которую ждёт excel:
1. Проверьте .php скрипт в Notepad++ - должна стоять кодировка UTF8 **без BOM**. Иначе уже BOM символы разрушат формат.
2. Поставьте в самом самом начале скрипта команду `ob_start();` а перед `$objWr->save('php://output');` добавьте `ob_end_clean();`. Если сработало - значит кто-то даёт в процессе выполнения лишние символы(нотисы, варнинги, просто пробел кто-то в начале файла сделал)
3. В заголовках ответа тоже укажите на всякий utf8 - чтобы не было проблем с кириллицей, для этого поменяйте заголовок на такой:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=UTF-8');
```